# Protected method not appear in Inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Why does the protected method not appear?
If I make any public, internal or protected internal method they get appear.

```
class A
{
    protected void AProtected() { }
}

class B:A
{
    protected void BProtected() { }
}

class C:B
{
    protected void CProtected() { }
}

class D:C
{
    protected void DProtected() { }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        D classD = new D();
        classD.               //no method appear.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `protected` methods are accessible to the current class and subclasses of that class. `Program` is not a subclass of `D`.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx)

> A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.

[Accessibility levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)

> [image]

Since I notice confusion: you can call those `protected` methods from *inside* the subclass but you cannot call them from *outside* the subclass onto that subclass.

This might illustrate it:

### Create two classes that don't have anything to do with eachother

*`MyMethod` is NOT accessible*

> [image]

### Add inheritance between these two classes

*`MyMethod` IS accessible from the subclass*

> [image]

### Try to call the method from another class

*`MyMethod` is NOT accessible*

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

Because that's the whole idea of `protected`. Protected members are only accessible by the declaring class and other classes that inherit from it.

You can find the official documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx).

Comment: then is should show at least one protected method i.e. where D is inheriting C so it should display the CProtected();    D classD = new D();
        classD.CProtected();

Answer (score 0):

Because `protected` methods are not visible outside of the class or a class that inherits from that class.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx):

> The protected keyword is a member access modifier. 
>       A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.

You could call `DProtected()` within `D`, but not outside of `D`.

Answer (score 0):

Protected is similar to private in that in can only be accessed from within the class, but has the added benefit of being accessible from inherited classes.

Your class `Program` (and its main method) are not able to access private or protected methods of your other classes, only public.

Answer (score 0):

Protected methods can be called *within derived classes* only:

```
class A {
  // This method can be called within derived classes only
  protected void ProtectedA() {...}
  // This method can be called within classes that are in the same namespace
  internal void InternalA() {...} 
  // This method can be called either within derived classes only or
  // within classes that are in the same namespace
  protected internal void InternalOrProtectedA() {...} 
}

class B: A {
  protected void ProtectedB() {
    // You can call A.ProtectedA() here since B is derived from A
  }
}

class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args)
    // You can NOT call A.ProtectedA() here since B is NOT derived from A
    // But you can call
    //   A.InternalA() since classes Program and A are in the same namespace
    //   A.InternalOrProtectedA() on the same reason
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one to watch out for is if the method in the derived class is static. You can't call instance methods from a static method in a derived class, regardless of visibility/access modifiers.

If you have

```
namespace A
{
    public class AClass
    {
        public void MethodCall()
        {
            xxx
        }
    }
}
```

**Works**

```
namespace B
{
    public class BClass : A.AClass
    {
        public void Go()
        {
            A.AClass.MethodCall();
        }
    }
}
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
namespace B
{
    public class BClass : A.AClass
    {
        public **static** void Go()
        {
            A.AClass.MethodCall();
        }
    }
}
```